# how to delete data in array list from another activity

Tags: android, arraylist

I have a class with a getView and it handle the the onclick listener that will delete data in Arraylist which is in another class that extends in activity the problem is it returns me a null pointer.

**Here is my activity which handles the Arraylist**

```
public ArrayList<String> imagesFileName = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;


//method for deleting data in array list and will going to use in another class
public void deleteFile(int i){
    imagesFileName.remove(i);
    mylist.remove(i);
    adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();

}
```

**Here is my class that holds a getView() and will going to use the method I declared in the activity**

```
Activity activity = new Activity();
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View rowView = null;
    try{
    rowView = inflater.inflate(resource, null, true);
    TextView textViewTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[0]);
    EditText textViewSubtitle = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(to[1]);
    TextView textViewSubtitle1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[2]);
    TextView textViewSubtitle2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[3]);
    final TextView textViewSubtitle3 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[4]);
    TextView textViewId = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(to[5]);

    final String id = textViewId.getText().toString();
        textViewSubtitle3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                activity.deleteFile(id);//here is my method in my Activiy
            }
        });
```

**When I use the method in the same activity it works. But when I'm using it to another class it return me an indexoutofbounds.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figure it out all I need is to join my Activity and the Class in one page for be able a Class to access my array list.

Answer (score 0):

Argument type of deleteFile() is integer, but you called it by passing string in getView() function. You may check this problem first.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would put the array in shared preferences. This means you would be accessing the data in a standard and well-understood way.